# Nautilus doesnt open applications with open with dialog

Tags: atom-editor, debian-based, nautilus

I recently installed Nautilus on my Parrot Security OS which is Debian based and installed it through synaptic, but now that im starting to use the application when i try to open a Floder with the Atom editor through the Open With dialog, it doesnt do anything, just a temporary window saying opening and the name of the folder, and thats it. I have tried to "debug" the application using the terminal and i got a hint that perhaps its some error related to the nautilus-python package, but dont know how to fix it, that package is version 2.6 i think. Any help will be great and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only needed to Install first Nautilus, then through Synaptic, find all the packages related to Nautilus and upgrade them and install them, that way Nautilus is complete and not "buggy" when you try to use it.